# Do we have any CROSS APPLY feature in SAP HANA?

Tags: sql, hana

How can we join a table and a function in SAP HANA SQL, I checked but CROSS Apply does not work in HANA as in SQL Server.

Does anyone with HANA background have any solution to this?

How can SAP miss these important features like this?

Comment: What's your concrete usecase?

Answer (score 1):

CROSS JOIN is a SQL standard function and HANA implements it in a compliant way.
Current HANA version support LATERAL JOIN  which is equivalent to CROSS APPLY if I understand that correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Can you show an example using LATERAL JOIN ?

Comment: straight from the documentation (https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/20fcf24075191014a89e9dc7b8408b26.html?locale=en-US) : SELECT TA.a1, TB.b1 FROM TA, LATERAL (SELECT b1, b2 FROM TB WHERE b3 = TA.a3) TB WHERE TA.a2 = TB.b2;

Comment: @DB_Dentist Please consider accepting this answer if it was helpful resolving the issue

Comment: The link to the docs takes you to the latest version (2.0 SP07 in 2023) but the description of `lateral_table_expression` hasn't appeared since the SPS 05 version. You can change version to see it. The docs state it should work with a LEFT OUTER JOIN but I couldn't get anything other than cross-join syntax accepted. I wonder if it's a feature that is going to quietly disappear.