# SAP HANA - how to use LEFT LATERAL JOIN

Tags: sql, hana, sapb1

SAP Business One | HANA Version: 2.0 SPS05

I'm attempting to get a query of all vendors and the `DocNum` and `DocDate` of their last purchase order.

With a CTE and window function:

```
WITH Last_PO AS (
 SELECT 
  "CardCode", "DocNum", "DocDate"
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "CardCode" ORDER BY "DocEntry" DESC) row_num
 FROM OPOR
 WHERE "CANCELED" = 'N'
)

SELECT
 OCRD."CardCode"
 ,OCRD."CardName"
 ,Last_PO."DocNum" AS "Last PO"
 ,Last_PO."DocDate" AS "Last PO Date"
FROM
 OCRD LEFT JOIN Last_PO on Last_PO.row_num = 1 AND Last_PO."CardCode" = OCRD."CardCode"
WHERE
 OCRD."CardType" = 'S'
ORDER BY
 OCRD."CardCode"
```

When attempting to use a  LATERAL join, I get the error `incorrect syntax near "WHERE"`:

```
SELECT
 OCRD."CardCode"
 ,OCRD."CardName"
 ,Last_PO."DocNum" AS "Last PO"
 ,Last_PO."DocDate" AS "Last PO Date"
FROM
 OCRD LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT "DocNum", "DocDate"
  FROM OPOR 
  WHERE "CANCELED" = 'N' AND "CardCode" = OCRD."CardCode"
  ORDER BY "DocEntry" DESC
  LIMIT 1
) Last_PO ON TRUE
WHERE
 OCRD."CardType" = 'S'
ORDER BY
 OCRD."CardCode"
```

I found this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72067288/do-we-have-any-cross-apply-feature-in-sap-hana#comment136739325_72075910), so maybe this feature never worked correctly:

> The link to the docs takes you to the latest version (2.0 SP07 in
> 2023) but the description of lateral_table_expression hasn't appeared
> since the SPS 05 version. You can change version to see it. The docs
> state it should work with a LEFT OUTER JOIN but I couldn't get
> anything other than cross-join syntax accepted. I wonder if it's a
> feature that is going to quietly disappear.

Comment: the `LATERAL JOIN` type is in the SQL standards and I'm not aware of it quietly disappearing  (in general) see: https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/11/whats-new-in-hana-2.0-sps04-sql/

Comment: LATERAL JOIN is supported in HANA 2.0 SPS04 onwards : https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/11/whats-new-in-hana-2.0-sps04-sql/

Comment: There are no LATERAL JOINS, only **LATERAL derived tables**.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work changing the ON condition (`ON TRUE` doesn't seem to work on HANA), but it's ultra slow compared to the CTE version. I only have access to the B1 app itself, so I have no way to profile it, but it takes 3-5 seconds to execute while the CTE version is instant.

```
SELECT
 OCRD."CardCode"
 ,OCRD."CardName"
 ,Last_PO."DocNum" AS "Last PO"
 ,Last_PO."DocDate" AS "Last PO Date"
FROM
 OCRD LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT "CardCode", "DocNum", "DocDate"
  FROM OPOR 
  WHERE "CANCELED" = 'N' AND "CardCode" = OCRD."CardCode"
  ORDER BY "DocEntry" DESC
  LIMIT 1
) Last_PO ON Last_PO."CardCode" = OCRD."CardCode" -- or 'ON 1 = 1'
WHERE
 OCRD."CardType" = 'S'
ORDER BY
 OCRD."CardCode"
```